# How to know if a basement is dry enough to finish

Tags: basement, moisture

I am looking to finish/remodel my below grade basement. I am worried about moisture issues. I have owned the house for 2 years and there is no evidence of standing water in the basement. The floor is currently covered with very old (maybe 40 years) vinyl tile. How do I know if it the basement is dry enough to be able to refinish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you're asking exactly, but the bigger question is probably whether you'll be able to manage moisture once the basement is finished. If you can run a dehumidifier during the summer months and prevent extreme humidity, and if all drainage issues are handled, you should be fine.

Be cognizant of the right way to install vapor barriers and other moisture-handling mechanisms in your area. The best approach depends on a number of factors, such as climate, soil conditions, foundation type, etc. Speaking with local builders and inspectors would be wise.